# WILL Ubuntu 18.10 operate on Toshiba Satellite-L505D

Tags: boot

So far I'm at the boot up and creating user name smooth right now but I have not run browsers which is all I really want to do. I have 3gbs of RAM and I believe this is 2.12ghz have to look again. Anyone else running this? This was a PC the customer never came back to pick up.

Comment: Download Ubuntu and try it.   https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install  Whilst I don't know your hardware, you can test Ubuntu on the actual hardware (testing it will have lower performance as everything will be running from compressed images on a thumb-drive, but it's still a great indicator).  If you're unhappy, I'd suggest a lighter flavor (Lubuntu, Xubuntu etc)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. I tested it 2 months ago. Obviously you have to be very patient during the install process (it was a bit slow for me) but other than that you are good to go. And yes it is a 2.1Ghz. Everything worked correctly. From the Ati graphics driver which I thought it would fail but it worked perfectly to the lan connection.